# Python upload fails (only half of the file uploaded)

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, artifactory, httplib

I have a Python uploader function which fails because it only uploads a part of the file (tested with binaries and text files).

```
def upload_u(logger, encoded_credentials, local_file_path, remote_path):
  logger.info("Uploading %s to %s...", local_file_path, remote_path)
    url = "https://my-artifactory-repo-site.org/artifactory/my-artifactory-repository/%s" % remote_path
    authentication_header = "Basic %s" % encoded_credentials

    logger.info("Calling %s", url)
    f = open(local_file_path, READ_FILE_AS_BINARY)
    request = urllib2.Request(url, data=f.read())
    f.close()
    request.get_method = lambda: PUT_REQUEST
    request.add_header(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_KEY, authentication_header)
    request.add_header('Content-Length', os.path.getsize(local_file_path))
    request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
    print request.headers

    response = None
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        print response.read()
        response.close()
        logger.info("Upload finished. (Status Code: HTTP %d)", response.getcode())
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        if e.code not in OK_STATUS_CODES:
            logger.error("Upload failed.\nStatus Code: HTTP %d\nReason: %s", e.code, "TODO")
            raise UploaderError("Upload failed with status code %d" % e.code)
        else:
            logger.info("Upload finished. (Status Code: HTTP %d)", e.code)
```

This is **urllib2**, but I have also tried it with urllib and httplib. It only works with Requests but I could not use that library because I have to use a built in one.

I have also tried to:

- open file not in binary mode
- pass file-like object instead of content

Comment: So the file gets uploaded but it is not complete? Does it trigger the except?

Comment: What sizes are we talking about?  Some kB?  Some GB?  Is the size of the part which _gets_ uploaded always the same or does it vary?  Which sizes get uploaded?

Comment: No, it does not trigger the except. 
We have files with some KB and other ones with 10+ MB. The uploaded size is always the same (for the same file). I have also tried it without giving the content length.

Comment: What type of response do you get? have you checked the Artifactory log files?

Comment: What is the http status code that you see in the log?

Answer (score 0):

Unless `READ_FILE_AS_BINARY`, `PUT_REQUEST`, `AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_KEY` have some unusual values; your code should work as is and the issue is elsewhere.

For debugging, try this code that can upload large files that do not fit in memory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import mmap
import sys
from contextlib import closing
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

url, file_to_upload = sys.argv[1:3]
credentials = 'dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA=='

with open(file_to_upload,'rb') as file:
    with closing(mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)) as mm:
        request = Request(url, mm)
        request.get_method = lambda: "PUT"
        request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials)
        request.add_header("Content-type", "application/octet-stream")
        # Content-Length is set automatically
        with closing(urlopen(request)) as response:
            print(response.info())
```

If it also uploads only half of the file then the problem is not in your client Python code.